# Handlebars and nested data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

I need a help, consider the following json data:

```
var datas = {
    report_city: 'mycityname1',
    sites: [
        { site_name: "site1.com", visits: 100},
        { site_name: "site2.com", visits: 100},
    ]
};
```

**Handlebars Helper:**

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('average-visits', function(p_visits, p_sites) {

  var allVisits = 0;
  p_sites.forEach(function(item, index) {
    allVisits = allVisits + parseFloat(item['visits']);
  });


  var averageVisits = ((p_visits * 100) / allVisits);
  return averageVisits;
});
```

**HTML**

```
{{#each sites}}
      {{ site_name }} ( {{average-visits visits ../sites }}% )
{{/each}}
```

why don't work? p_site always return undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('average-visits', function(p_visits, p_sites) {
  var allVisits = 0;
  p_sites.forEach(function(item, index) {
    allVisits = allVisits + item.visits;
  });
  console.log('>>> ' + p_visits);


  var averageVisits = ((p_visits * 100) / allVisits);
  return averageVisits;
});
```

See [this jsBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qatos/1/).
Another way would be to define a computed property `averageVisits` on your controller.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object p_sites has no method 'forEach'

Comment: I'm not sure if you can pass an array in. Can you try putting a debugger statement before the `forEach`?

Comment: var p_sites = block.hash.sites;
return sites as string 'sites'

Comment: Can you put together a jsFiddle/jsBin?

Comment: Thank you! The best way, would be to define a computed property averageVisits on your controlle?

Comment: Well it really depends on how your code is structured, but it could make sense to do that. Or you could even define it on your model if that's appropriate.

Comment: And can I to use forEach in my model? its possible?
App.Report = DS.Model.extend({
 report_city: DS.attr('string'),
 sites: DS.attr('raw'),
});

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that within a computed property. But don't worry too much about it - the above works fine